# PowerShell script to change IE home page not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a PowerShell script to change the home page of IE 11 on a computer. Everything I've read online shows the same script, but when I execute it, it is not changing the value in the registry. Can someone help me troubleshoot what's wrong?

```
write "Setting google as IE homepage..."

$path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\'

$name = 'start page'

$value = 'http://www.google.com/'

Set-Itemproperty -Path $path -Name $name -Value $value
```

Comment: "*when I execute it, it is not changing the value in the registry*" - works for me. I opened ISE, pasted the script into the terminal, then checked in regedit - start page changed from about:blank to google. Describe exactly what you are doing to save, run, and check the script? (Edit your question and add details)

Comment: Sorry, so it is changing it in the registry. However, when I ope IE, the home page is not what it is showing in the registry. If you open up your IE, is it taking you to the right page?

Comment: i had to confirm in a yellow bar at the bottom of the screen, but yes it opens google.

Comment: OK, I see that now too. That's a little unfortunate since I'm trying to use this to automate staging of a laptop, and having to click that brings back in the human element. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must confirm the bottom message when you open IE